# Is it possible for a human to perform vaginal delivery without labor? Is there a name for such practice?

Tags: obstetrics, anesthesia, vaginal-delivery, birth, c-section

In obstetrics there is a notion of a delivery without labor via c-section under anasthesia. Is there a practice of vaginal delivery under anasthesia?